# Shebang automatically finding the most recent python 3 version

Tags: python-3.x, shebang

Let's say I have a python script that i want to run in Python 3.X on a couple different Linux machines.
Most of them only had python 2.7 installed originally, and that's the way their "Python" Symlink is pointing.

So, let's also assume each user installed his own version of python 3. This means that in each machine the /usr/bin/ directory can have things like Python3.4/Python3.5/Python3.6/etc, maybe even two of them or more, but there never is a Symlink called "Python3" pointing to anywhere.

I want my script to recognize the most recent python3 version the system has.
Well, it doesn't really have to be the script I guess, but I need a way that allows me to conveniently  apply it to a great number of machines.

So far I am using the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.x
```

Obviously, this only works when I specify one particular x but I need it to automatically recognize the python 3 version that a random machine has.

Is this possible?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shebang :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: As I said, there is no "Python3" Symlink, so when I use #!/usr/bin/env python3, It doesn't find anything.

Comment: which linux distribution did you use?

Comment: I'll eventually have many distributions to deal with at the same time, but let's say all the machines are CentOS, for now.